# Chrome headless CLI print-to-pdf keeps the url in the footer and improve the resolution

Tags: command-line-interface, google-chrome-headless

I am using chrome headless --print-to-pdf option via CLI. I have a couple of questions

- I try too many approaches to remove the page URL from the footer but nothing works 
  I tried to use css

  @page {
      margin: 0;
  }

  @media print {
      @page {
          margin: 0;
      }
      body { margin: 0; }
  }

by this I manage to hide the header like date and page name but not the footer Also the command `--no-margins` not helping here

- Is there a way to improve the image quality? I try to use `--window-size=1920,1080` but the quilty look not good still blurry 
  is there an option to modify the page's resolution in chrome headless
- is there a way to send a ticket with the header

I really appreciate any help or tip